# What is the difference between \titleformat and \titleformat*?

Tags: titlesec

I know that `\titleformat*` takes only two arguments. But I don't understand when to use which one.

Is there just more freedom with formatting in `\titleformat*` while `\titleformat` has preprogrammed formats?

Comment: [titlesec documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf), pages 3 and 4.

Comment: In short: `\titleformat`  is for the ‘advanced interface’ (full featured).